# Specify field projections in spring mongo db query

Tags: json, spring, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

```
{
    "_id":"1",
    "company":"ABCD",
    "Address":{
    "Location":"XYZ"
    },
    "empName":[{
    "ID":1,
    "Name":"test1"
    },
    "ID":2,
    "Name":"test2"
    },
    "ID":3,
    "Name":"test3"
    }]
}
```

am using mongoTemplate query,

```
Criteria findCriteria1 = Criteria.where("_id").is("1");
Criteria find2Criteria = Criteria.where("empName").elemMatch(Criteria.where("ID").is(1));
BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery(findCriteria1.getCriteriaObject(), find2Criteria.getCriteriaObject());
mongoTemplate.findOne(basicQuery, ClassName.class);
```

but my result as below with other fields displayed null.

```
{
    "_id":"1",
    "company":null,
    "Address":null,
    "empName":[{
    "ID":1,
    "Name":"test1"
    }]
}
```

my expected result should be like this,

```
"_id":"1",
"company":"ABCD",
"Address":{
"Location":"XYZ"
},
"empName":[{
"ID":1,
"Name":"test1"
}]
```

Can you please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Do Read the documentation for [Criteria](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html) and [BasicQuery](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/BasicQuery.html#BasicQuery-org.bson.Document-org.bson.Document-).

The second argument in this

```
BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery(findCriteria1.getCriteriaObject(), find2Criteria.getCriteriaObject());
```

is basically a projection. i.e. you are telling the driver to fetch only the fields mentioned in those. Hence other fields are not fetched and hence null.

If you want to fetch all fields this is what you should do in your case

```
    Criteria findCriteria1 = Criteria.where("_id").is("1");  
    Criteria find2Criteria = Criteria.where("empName").elemMatch(Criteria.where("ID").is(1));  
    BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery(findCriteria1.andOperator(find2Criteria).getCriteriaObject());
```

Comment: Thanks @pvpkiran for your comment. as am new to mongo db unable to use andperator as below ,BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery(findCriteria1.getCriteriaObject().andOperator(find2Criteria.getCriteriaObject());
mongoTemplate.findOne(basicQuery, ClassName.class); Can you please help on this?

Comment: what do you meant by unable to use. Are you getting any error?

Comment: yes, its compilation error. The method andOperator(DBObject) is undefined for the type DBObject

Comment: compiler shows add cast to DBObject and finally output is org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject

Comment: again edted. check now

Comment: BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery(); is showing error message as The constructor BasicQuery() is undefined. we don't have default constructor for this.

Comment: can you please help me to fix this issue ? Thanks in advnace

Comment: check now. I think it is similar to one of the previous versions. it should work

Comment: I tried , compiler asking to Cast argument 1 to 'DBObject'. when i cast it output returns error message org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject

Comment: Can you please help me on this to fix this issue?

Comment: I was checking some older docs. I have edited the answer for one last time. Check now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this time it is returning full collection and find2Criteria is not filtering here

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code.

You can chain the fields you require in the `Field` class.

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id").is("1");
Query query = new Query(criteria);
query.fields().elemMatch("empName", Criteria.where("ID").is(1)).include("company");
mongoTemplate.findOne(query , ClassName.class);
```